# Passport.js - Strategy parameters

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have a Node.js backend which I use to connect users with Facebook. However, I need to save some pieces of information that I would like to send as query parameters.

I have the following code, who save a user token to a database:

```
passport.use(
  'facebook',
  new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: keys.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.facebook.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: keys.facebook.callbackURL
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    facebook.saveUser(accessToken)
      .then((res) => {
        return done(null, true);
      });
  })
);
```

I need to save two more parameters: userLoginId, and userId. Is it possible to do this and add this to my saveUser() function? I don't think that using sessions would be a good idea as many users could be doing this operation at the same time.

Comment: "I don't think that using sessions would be a good idea as many users could be doing this operation at the same time." You can store session in the localStorage in the client side so that doesn't matter

Comment: If I do this, I will have to store my credentials in my front end. How to ensure that no-one accesses them?